# Invoke an instance method without specify the instance by Ruby meta programing?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

How to design the scope method to let it actually puts row.city?

```
row.scope do 
  puts city
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Object
  def scope(&block)
    instance_eval(&block)
  end
end

Thing = Struct.new(:city)
row = Thing.new "Bryn Athyn"

row.scope{ puts city }
#=> Bryn Athyn
```

If you don't want to monkey-patch Object, you could alternatively:

```
module Scopeable
  def scope(&block)
    instance_eval(&block)
  end
end

Thing = Struct.new(:city)
row = Thing.new "Bryn Athyn"
row.extend(Scopeable)

row.scope{ puts city }
#=> Bryn Athyn
```

Although given this, perhaps easiest is simply:

```
class Object
  alias_method :scope, :instance_eval
end
```

Or easier yet...just use "instance_eval" instead of "scope" :)

Comment: I noticed you can't change the instance in the block, `city = "something"` doesn't work there. :(

Comment: @Cheng That's only because Ruby cannot tell if you are calling an accessor method or setting a local variable. The same problem occurs in instance methods of any class. Try `self.city = "something"` instead.

Comment: Got it. But that's what I want to archive. Hmm, it could be done by check local_variables. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using `instance_eval`:

```
class RowClass
  attr_accessor :city

  def scope(&blk)
    instance_eval(&blk)
  end
end

row = RowClass.new
row.city = "bla"

row.scope do 
  puts city # prints "bla"
end
```

Comment: To extend this question further, what if city isn't an attr_accessor, but an dynamic method that handled via method_missing?

I could make them a attr_accessor for now, but would like to know what if I couldn't.

Comment: @Cheng: No difference. Writing `city` within the block will have the same effect as writing `row.city` no matter how the call to `city` is handled.